# Switching xib views without carrying commands from previous screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been using storyboards since I began using xCode. Today I have been trying out the old way with xib files.

My first view has an accelerometer code that is still active when I am on the second view.

Is there a way to **stop** the second view controller from using code from the first view?

I am importing the second views header file into the first views implementation file, is that correct? If I remove that import I get errors.

```
//
//  ViewController.m



#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self startAccel];
    //[self view];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self stopAccel];
    //[self view];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

    {

    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));

}



-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

    double const kThreshold = 1.7;
//    double const kThreshold = 2.0;
    if ( fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kThreshold){


        int randomNumber = arc4random() % 3 + 1;

        NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber] ofType:@"wav"]];

        AVAudioPlayer * soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

        [soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [soundPlayer play];

    }
}


-(void)startAccel{
    UIAccelerometer * accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = .25;
}

-(void)stopAccel{
    UIAccelerometer * accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = nil;
}




-(IBAction)View2:(id)sender;{
    ViewController2 *V2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]
                                              initWithNibName:@"ViewController2"
                                              bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:V2.view];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The second controller doesn't really **use** code from the first but, if you called startAccelerometerUpdates while you were displaying your first view, you might want to stop them as you're about to present the second one if it doesn't need them.

Comment: I added the source code to the original question above. Can you see something I am doing wrong to make it use this accelerometer on the next view controller?

Comment: Other than the fact that, according to the docs, you should be calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` and `[super viewWillDisappear:animated]`, nothing jumps out.  I don't **think** that would cause this problem (but I'm not sure).  I'd be tempted to write out NSLog() messages in startAccel and stopAccel to make sure they were being called when I thought they were.